# Can't boot Ubuntu after replacing Motherboard

Tags: boot, ssd, motherboard

After replacing my motherboard (from ASUS to ASROCK) I can't seem to boot into my Ubuntu SSD, it just seems to be gone. I have one W10 SSD and another Ubuntu 20.04 SSD and I used to have a boot swap enabled that'd let me choose between them, but after replacing my motherboard I had to reinstall W10 but I read that I could keep my Ubuntu intact. W10 runs just fine, and I know the Ubuntu SSD is working and being read because I can boot up the Ubuntu LiveCD, mount said SSD and see that all my files and everything are still in there just fine.

However the Ubuntu boot just WON'T show up in my boot loader in the motherboard or even EasyBCD. I have turned off Secure Boot and Fast Boot, changed cables, SATA ports, updated motherboard drivers, updated GRUB2 through an Ubuntu LiveCD, and even updated initramfs for good measure. I'm not sure what to do now.

I've looked all over for a solution but nobody seems to have the exact same problem, just similar ones:

[Why am I unable to boot Ubuntu after motherboard change?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208486/why-am-i-unable-to-boot-ubuntu-after-motherboard-change)

[Motherboard replaced - How can I recover GRUB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/880662/motherboard-replaced-how-can-i-recover-grub)

[Ubuntu 16.10 won't boot after motherboard replacement - GRUB issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897661/ubuntu-16-10-wont-boot-after-motherboard-replacement-grub-issue)

It's not that the boot fails or anything, it's like it doesn't exist for my system, but like I said I can just mount and see that everything is still there just fine.

**-- Edit**
Here's the Boot-Repair report:
[paste.ubuntu.com/p/FCJMWBn8cD](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/FCJMWBn8cD)

Comment: Even new motherboard may need UEFI firmware update. And SSDs may need firmware updates. Are both systems installed in UEFI boot mode? Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: did Windows perhaps overwrite the boot partition on your Ubuntu disk?

Comment: Oh wow, I actually didn't expect to get responses so quick, thank you!

oldfred:
I did as you said, here: 
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/FCJMWBn8cD/
Taking a quick glance over I remember that I once had a problem with where the OS was installed on the SSD cylinder, and I had to transfer it to the beginning of it, and I remember having to mess with fstab at the time. It worked fine though, and I continued to use it for a pretty long time afterwards with no problems, even.

Ester:
I read that Windows loves to do that so I had no other storage installed when installing windows, so prob not